# How to list all installed applications in the device and allows the user to set individual password for each app?

Tags: android

I have the code for listing installed apps in device but when i click for e.g Camera app, it opens the app. What i wanna do is not open the app, but locking it with password(a lock screen appears before that particular app launch), is it possible ?

Here is my code for listing installed apps :

```
private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.application);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
    try {
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

        if (intent != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(Application.this, e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(Application.this, e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName) != null) {
                applist.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return applist;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(Application.this,R.layout.list_item, applist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setListAdapter(listadaptor);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Application.this, null,
                "Loading application info...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

The listing installed apps' code i found on youtube, here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6R-sc2QMVM

I'm new in developing android and I'm really interested in developing my own app locker. Sorry for my bad english, any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Do it very simple in this following method

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
if(passwordExist(app.packageName)){
// show the password screen here
}
else{
 try {
    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

    if (intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(Application.this, e.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(Application.this, e.getMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Write your own method as follows

```
public boolean passwordExist(String packageName){
checkPasswordForPackagename(packageName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no listener for app opening action. However, you can achieve it with a hack via your own lock app's `Service`. In your service, you must check current app is locked app or not each seconds.

```
//Get current open app.
private String getTopPackageName() { 
    try {
        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager
                .getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        LogUtils.d("TopPackage: " + ar.topActivity.getPackageName());
        return ar.topActivity.getPackageName();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
// Run this class every seconds to check app should be locked or not.
private class AppCheckerTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LogUtils.i("---- check top app ---");
        String topPackageName = getTopPackageName();
        //getLockedApps() is your own function which list all locked packaged
        if (getLockedApps().contains(topPackageName)) {
            // Top app is locked app
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the service located ?